# How to remove event listener manually in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I'm using react hooks and I want to conditionally add and remove listener (not only in case my component unmounts).
My component adds the listener however never removes it. Why is it so?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    }

    if (!isPlaying) {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't add / remove the eventlistener when you setState of isPlaying?

Comment: I don't use setState at all since I receive it from redux store. Moreover, I initially attributed the failure of removal to the capturing option, but in fact, the problem was in argument of useEfect, at first, I had none

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that I forgot to resubscribe for `isPlaying` property. Without any argument, useEffect runs only once and then clears on destroy.
In the code above, useEffect is called as it does in componentDidMount, and by chance, `isPlaying` property equals to true, so the eventListener is added. But when `isPlaying` becomes falsy, the useEffect is never called again and obviously, never removes the eventlistener.
The fix is to pass `isPlaying` as a second argument to useEffect:

```
... return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, [isPlaying]);
```